# Two questions about the results regarding power series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

1. If radius of convergence of $\sum c_{n}x^{n}$ and $\sum d_{n}x^{n}$ is given say $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ respectively,then how can I find the radius of convergence of $\sum (c_{n}+d_{n})x^{n}$
2. Given power series say $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ has radius of convergence $R$,then what is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_{n}^{m}x^{n}$,$m$ is positive integer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309466/radius-of-convergence-of-a-sum-of-power-series This post partially answers your first question.

Comment: You can lose the privilege of asking questions, omkar, if you continue posting low quality questions.  So please take suggestions in comments and improve your posts.  This is not a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: Ask **one question only, per post**,

Comment: Sorry..I will keep this in mind for future..but seriously, I have lots of respect for this site and I have never use for such homework purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**just a hint **

Let $a=\min (a_1,a_2). $

if $|x|<a $  then $\sum (c_n+d_n)x^n $ converges .

for the second, the ratio $\frac {a_n^m}{a_{n+1}^m} $ goes to $R^m $ if $R $ is the radius of $\sum a_nx^n $.